# How to get rows or cells from json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am having an issue getting rows from JSON and storing it in a separate {} object. This is how I structure my data.

[image]

After trying different techniques, I finally think this is close but not what I am looking for.

```
for(let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++){
   Object.values(allData.analysis[key]).slice(1).map(val => {
     console.log({[cols[i]]: val[i]})
   })
}
```

**allData** contains all the data including the header

```
name,age,gender
John Deo,45,male
Mary Jeo,54,female
Saly Meo,55,female
```

**cols** contains only the header

---

After running the above code this is what I got.

**What I have so far.**

[image]

**What I am looking for to accomplish.**

[image]

I am happy to provide more sample codes!

Comment: You can use `reduce` function to get the object you want.

Comment: Is it a csv that you're getting it from?

Comment: Yes, I upload into firebase as a csv but reading it from json.

Comment: it may help to think of this "JSON object" as an javascript object - because 1. it is a javascript object, and 2. there's no such thing as a JSON object, JSON is a string, but once you've parsed it you're dealing with a plain ol' boring javascript object

Comment: do you have the sample allData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More answer for dynamic data like you add more header

```js
var temporary = [
  "name,age,gender,status",
  "John Deo,45,male,single",
  "Mary Jeo,54,female,married",
  "Saly Meo,55,female,married"
];

// for dynamic header

var headers = temporary[0].split(',');
var data = [];

for(var x = 1; x < temporary.length; x++) {

   var dataToInsert = {};
   // split values to convert to array
   var values = temporary[x].split(',');

   // loop inside headers
   for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      var key = headers[i];
      // assign values according to match indexes
      dataToInsert[key] = values[i];
   }
   data.push(dataToInsert);
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without sample data structure, but you could do something like this and adapt.

```js
const allData = [
  ["John Deo", 45, "male"],
  ["Mary Jeo", 54, "female"],
  ["Saly Meo", 55, "female"]
];

const data = allData.reduce((accum, curr) => {
  let obj = {};
  obj.name = curr[0];
  obj.age = curr[1];
  obj.gender = curr[2];
  return [...accum, obj];
}, []);

console.log(data);
```